# undefined reference to `main' error in gcc 4.7

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I created a program in C and I tried to compile it. When I use my gcc 4.8.1 compiler in Widows everything worked and my program too.

I compiled with the following arguments:

```
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm children.c
```

But in linux I getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is that? My programm is working and I can't understand why I getting compiling errors in linux.

My code is:

```
/*---------------------*/
/* included files      */
/*---------------------*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*---------------------*/
/* defined constants   */
/* for restriction     */
/*---------------------*/
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 1000000
#define IOERROR 5   // 'Input/Output Error'

/*---------------------*/
/* function prototypes */
/*---------------------*/
int main();
FILE *read_input(const char *filename_r);
int count_children(FILE *input);
int pass_heights(FILE *input, int *children, int size);
int check_tall(const int *children, int size);
void write_output(const int total,const char *filename_w);


/*---------------------*/
/* start of program    */
/*---------------------*/
int main() {

    const char *filename_r = "xxx.in";
    const char *filename_w = "xxx.out";

    FILE *input = read_input(filename_r);

    int size = count_children(input);

    int *children = malloc(size * sizeof *children);
    if (children==NULL)
    exit(1); //General application error

    pass_heights(input, children, size);

    fclose(input);

    int total = check_tall(children, size);

    free(children);

    write_output(total,filename_w);

    return 0;
}

FILE *read_input(const char *filename_r) {

    FILE *input = fopen(filename_r, "r");

    if(input == NULL)
    exit(IOERROR);

    return input;
}


int count_children(FILE *input) {

    int count = 0;
    fscanf(input, "%d",&count);

    if(count > MAX || count < MIN)
    exit(1); //General application error

    return count;
}


int pass_heights(FILE *input, int *children, int size) {

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    fscanf(input, "%d",&children[i]);

    return *children;
}


int check_tall(const int *children, int size) {

    int total = 0;
    int tmp_max = 0;
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(children[i] > tmp_max) {
            tmp_max = children[i];
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}


void write_output(const int total,const char *filename_w) {

    FILE *output = fopen(filename_w, "w");

    if(output == NULL)
    exit(IOERROR); 

    fprintf(output, "%d\n", total);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: You skipped the most important information, how are you compiling the program?

Comment: any reason you have a forward declaration of `main()`?

Comment: ok I update my code. No reason for a forward declaration of main() just I get everything in place

Comment: What is `-DCONTEST` for, I don't see that in your code.

Comment: it is for a project and our teachers want to compile our codes with that arguments. Neither I can't undrrstand what most of them need.

Comment: did you try putting the library-linking after the _filename_? something like `gcc children.c -std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm `

Comment: @NikosKLon I don't know what to tell you, the error means that there is no definition of `main()` in your code, but there is. So try to copy paste the code in a different file. Also, what Linux distro are you using?

Comment: I don't know. You see I upload my file to a automatic network test system. I know just that they use linux, 32bit If i understand the error correctly, and use the above arguments

Comment: Doesn't happen here. Since we cannot verify the remote system is indeed doing what it claims it's doing, the situation is more or less hopeless. You can only try and convince your higher-ups that their system is broken. Submit a program that only contains `int main(){return 0;}` and demonstrate the output.

Comment: Perhaps the implementation does not support `int main()`. Try using the standard form `int main (void)`. And no, those two forms do not have the same meaning.

Comment: @Lundin I tried it and nothing changes

Comment: @n.m. I have posted also other two programms and the system responced correctly.

Comment: also the system taked the `int main(){return 0;}` file correctly also with the headers.

Comment: So you can divide and conquer. Remove code from the program and submit until it builds. Since we know a trivial program can be built, it will eventually happen. You will arrive at a minimal non-buildable program such that removing one line makes it buildable. We then can look at that line.

Comment: In my system it compiles ok (well, not ok, with warnings)...  In my system it does compile with all the flags you used (it generates a.out, as you have not said the name of executable in the command line i.e. `-o children`, for example)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you edited all the code out of your question?

Comment: @BillLynch  yes just to update with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

You used `-static` option, which modifies the way executable is linked.

I was unable to reproduce your exact error message, but on my Linux it says that it is unable to link with `-lc` in static mode, and under my OSX it says that it is unable to locate `-lcrt0.o`. For me in both case, this means that the system is unable to locate the static stub.

If you remove `-static` it should work. If not, your problem is very strange.

Comment: I don't have any option to change the arguments of the compiler

Comment: `-static` is ok (it's needed to link statically) and no need of `-lc` (automatically included by the compiler) (also no need for `-lm`)  These are unrelated things to the problem.  Please, answer to the question, not to unrelated things.

Comment: @LuisColorado I never said to use `-lc` I said that on my machine, using `-static` leads to problems and one problem is that the link with the c-stub (`-lc` option of the linker) cause problems. Use `-v` and you will see what I mean...

Comment: It's evident he wants to compile a static executable, and `-static` is not related to the error message he receives (no `main()` in linking executable)  so you are trying without thinking on unrelated things to see if this leads to a working solution.  The problem is the building system is not finding the right file to compile, as it complaints about not having `main()` and the does have it. You are not helping this way, so you'd better to don't mess.

Answer (score 0):

The error you show indicates the linker is not finding the `main()` function in your code.  As it is evident that you have included it in the source file, it is also evident you are not compiling with that command line (or you are compiling in other directory where you have a non-main() source called `children.c`, perhaps the build system makes a `touch children.c` if it doesn't find the source, and then compiles it  --on that case it will not have a `main()` routine).  Check that the files are properly created and where, as I think you aren't compiling that file anyway.

Try to use simple options before you go to more complicated ones.  Try something like:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o children children.c
```

before trying to experiment with optimization or static linking anyway.  Also, dynamic linking is normally better than static, so you'll get smaller executables (8Kb vs. 800Kb, and multiple copies of libc loaded per executable). Also, you don't need to include `-lm` as you aren't using any of the `<math.h>` functions (having it doesn't hurt anyway).

I have compiled your source with the following command line without any problem, but I do have support for statically linked executables and perhaps you don't (the command line I have put above would work in any linux, I suppose)

```
$ make CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST' LDFLAGS='-s -static -lm' children
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST  -s -static -lm  children.c   -o children
children.c: In function ‘pass_heights’:
children.c:81:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
children.c: In function ‘count_children’:
children.c:69:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I use `gcc 4.6.3`, but it might not be an issue.

Comment: And so you tried without `-static` that is a requirement as you said ?

Comment: Nope, i tried with it, if you look I used the command `make CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST' LDFLAGS='-s -static -lm' children` that forces **make(1)** to use `-s` `-static` and `-lm` options on linking, as required.  It uses all the options in the question. Even the unneded `-lm` to link the math routines.